# Cannot launch AVD into emmulator Android Studio 2.1.2

Tags: android-studio

Cannot launch AVD in emulator.

**Output:**

```
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
qemu-system-i386.exe: -drive if=none,index=1,id=cache,file=C:\Users\Dave\.android\avd\Bori_Phone.avd/cache.img: could not open disk image
C:\Users\Dave\.android\avd\Bori_Phone.avd/cache.img: Could not open 'C:\Users\Dave\.android\avd\Bori_Phone.avd/cache.img': Invalid argument
```

please I don't know what to do